# Proper way to wait for async data to store in state in React or React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I need to get data from my SQLite database and then save it in my component's state. The database part is working fine, the problem is that it doesn't get saved to state quite quickly enough. If I add some artificial delay with setTimeout then it works fine. How could I better tie these things together so that it all works with the correct order and timing without a million callbacks?

This doesn't work:

```
let returnedData;
// This function works, the data comes back correctly eventually
returnedData = getDataFromDB();
this.setState({
    dbData: returnedData //but returnedData is still empty at this point
  })
// Data is not back in time to see in the variable or in state:
console.log(returnedData); // Undefined
console.log(this.state.dbData); // Undefined
```

But this does work:

```
let returnedData;
returnedData = getDataFromDB();

// If I add this tiny delay, it all works
setTimeout(function(){
     this.setState({
         dbData: returnedData
     })
     console.log(returnedData); // Shows correct data
     console.log(this.state.dbData); // Shows correct data
},100);
```

I would like to try to find a way for this to work without the artificial delay. I will need to do about 3 of these database queries in componentWillMount as my component is loading and will need to know that I have the data back before I render the component.

Thanks!

Comment: Use async and await.

Comment: returnedData = await getDataFromDB();

Answer (score 1):

Use the `componentDidMount` lifecycle hook to obtain async data when a component is initialized. This should be done in the component that is using the asynchronously obtained data, or the closest common ancestor for data that is used by multiple components. The reason for this is to reduce the amount of re-rendered components once the async retrieval has completed.

> Keep in mind you will also need to account for a *loading* state, before your async data is available.

Below is a basic example of the principles.

```
class ComponentThatRequiresAsyncData extends PureComponent {
    constructor( props ) {
        super( props );

        // initialize state
        this.state = {
            data: null
        }
    }

    // handle async operation in this lifecycle method to ensure
    // component has mounted properly
    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get( "some_url" )
            .then( ( response ) => {
                // once you have your data use setState to udpate state
                this.setState( ( prevState, props ) => {
                    return { data: response.data };
                })
            })
            .catch( ( error ) => {
                // handle errors
            });
    }

    render() {
        const { data } = this.state;
        return (
            {
                data ?
                    <WhatEverIWantToDoWithData data={ data } /> :
                    <p>Loading...</p>
          }
        );
    }
}
```

Use the same idea for data that needs to be loaded because of an event, such as a button click. Instead of using `componentDidMount` you would make your own method, make your async call and update state via `setState` in the `then` method of your http call. Just make sure you bind the `this` context of your method in your constructor if you're using it as an event handler.

Hope this helps. If you have any questions please ask!